# DayNight theme always shows night theme

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've created a new project that only includes a very simple activity that uses the new Day/Night theme. 
Even when calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` in a static block on the application class AND calling `getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` in the activity, the activity is showing the night theme. 
I've set a break point on the activity and its reporting that the UI mode is night, so I've got no idea why it's refusing to show the day theme.

I'm compiling against/targetting API 23 and testing on a Nexus 5 running Marshmallow

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201910.

Comment: @alanv damn, thats exactly what it is. If you'd like, put that into an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35701225/859190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201910. This will be fixed in the 23.2.1 bugfix release.

For now, you can force the theme to re-apply using the new configuration in your `Activity.onCreate()` by calling

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_<whatever>, true);
```

where `<whatever>` is the theme that you're using in that activity. Once you update to 23.2.1, you will not need this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to call `yourAppCompatActivity.getDelegate().applyDayNight();`.